# How to increase ubuntu server root partition size with ESXI?

Tags: server, partitioning, 22.04

I have the plex server installed my ubuntu server, and I need to increase the root partition size as that's where the media files are store.

```
root@ubuntusrv:~$ df -h
Filesystem                         Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev                               7.8G     0  7.8G   0% /dev
tmpfs                              1.6G  1.3M  1.6G   1% /run
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv   12G  9.6G  1.3G  89% /
tmpfs                              7.9G  4.0K  7.9G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs                              5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs                              7.9G     0  7.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/loop0                          62M   62M     0 100% /snap/core20/1587
/dev/loop2                          68M   68M     0 100% /snap/lxd/22753
/dev/loop3                          68M   68M     0 100% /snap/lxd/21835
/dev/loop1                          62M   62M     0 100% /snap/core20/1611
/dev/loop4                          44M   44M     0 100% /snap/snapd/14978
/dev/loop5                          47M   47M     0 100% /snap/snapd/16292
/dev/sda2                          1.5G  205M  1.2G  15% /boot
tmpfs                              1.6G     0  1.6G   0% /run/user/1000
root@ubuntusrv:~$ cd /opt/plexmedia/
root@ubuntusrv:/opt/plexmedia$ ls
Movies  TV
root@ubuntusrv:/opt/plexmedia$
```

I have very limited experience with linux and I'm getting started.

Am I right in thinking that the root partition is the one I need to resize?

When I google for this I keep getting articles about sda sizes which I donn't understand.

Can someone give me the exact steps to fix this?

I have already provisioned 1000GB space on the esxi server for this ubuntu server vm and now need to allocate it to the root partition.

Adding `sudo ls -lA /home/<username>/` - to check encryption of the root partition.

```
username@ubuntusrv:/opt/plexmedia$ sudo ls -lA /home/username/
total 81408
-rw------- 1 username username     2133 Aug 25 19:57 .bash_history
-rw-r--r-- 1 username username      220 Feb 25  2020 .bash_logout
-rw-r--r-- 1 username username     3771 Feb 25  2020 .bashrc
drwx------ 2 username username     4096 Jul 25 07:01 .cache
-rw-rw-r-- 1 username username    14211 May 11 07:17 expedition1_Installer_latest.tgz
drwxr-xr-x 3 username username     4096 Jul 25 07:16 expedition1_Installer_v2.1
-rw-rw-r-- 1 username username 83309356 Jun 30 02:46 plexmediaserver_1.27.2.5929-a806c5905_amd64.deb
-rw-r--r-- 1 username username      807 Feb 25  2020 .profile
drwx------ 2 username username     4096 Jul 25 06:56 .ssh
-rw-r--r-- 1 username username        0 Jul 25 07:01 .sudo_as_admin_successful
-rw------- 1 username username      110 Aug 27 13:56 .Xauthority
```

Adding some more details like `lsblk`

```
root@ubuntusrv:~# lsblk
NAME                      MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
loop0                       7:0    0   62M  1 loop /snap/core20/1587
loop1                       7:1    0   62M  1 loop /snap/core20/1611
loop2                       7:2    0 67.8M  1 loop /snap/lxd/22753
loop3                       7:3    0 67.2M  1 loop /snap/lxd/21835
loop4                       7:4    0 43.6M  1 loop /snap/snapd/14978
loop5                       7:5    0   47M  1 loop /snap/snapd/16292
sda                         8:0    0 1000G  0 disk
├─sda1                      8:1    0    1M  0 part
├─sda2                      8:2    0  1.5G  0 part /boot
└─sda3                      8:3    0 23.5G  0 part
  └─ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv 253:0    0 11.8G  0 lvm  /
sr0                        11:0    1 1024M  0 rom


root@ubuntusrv:~# pvs
  PV         VG        Fmt  Attr PSize   PFree
  /dev/sda3  ubuntu-vg lvm2 a--  <23.50g 11.75g

root@ubuntusrv:~# vgs
  VG        #PV #LV #SN Attr   VSize   VFree
  ubuntu-vg   1   1   0 wz--n- <23.50g 11.75g


root@ubuntusrv:~# lvs
  LV        VG        Attr       LSize   Pool Origin Data%  Meta%  Move Log Cpy%Sync Convert
  ubuntu-lv ubuntu-vg -wi-ao---- <11.75g

root@ubuntusrv:~# ls -lah /dev/mapper/
total 0
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root      80 Aug 25 13:39 .
drwxr-xr-x 19 root root    4.1K Aug 25 13:39 ..
crw-------  1 root root 10, 236 Aug 26 06:08 control
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root       7 Aug 26 06:08 ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv -> ../dm-0

root@ubuntusrv:~#
```

Adding my esxi settings here, which I changed from 25 gb to 1000gb:

[esxi VM settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zlqJc.png)

Comment: It looks like you have encrypted the system partition, called `/` when your installed Ubuntu in your VMware host. This makes resizing the lvm considerably difficult. Please [edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1426003/edit) and add if you used the encryption option during installation.

Comment: @user68186 how do I check that? I ran `sudo ls -lA /home/<username>/`  - is this the output you want me to add?